# PHP check if alternate username exists with foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

On my site, I have a registration page in PHP.
Someone can mimic `Ashley` by making `AshIey`.
I do not want this to happen. They replace lowercase `L` with capital `I`.
The string is `$username` and I wanted to check if it contained a capital 'I'.
If it did, I would set a new string and use an SQL query to see if it existed.
But hat if the username has multiple capital I letters in it? Like `DaryII`.
I was thinking of doing a foreach statement but didn't know what to do.
If anyone could give me a little demo of what I need to do, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I DID IT!!!

```
if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z\d\s]|[^A-Z\s]I|[A-Z]I[a-z]/', $username)) {
die("That username is unavailable for registration.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like Kasia Gogolek suggested, you might be interested in the `str_replace()` function that PHP offers. You can use it like that:

`$username = str_replace('I', 'l', $username);`

Alternatively, you might want to use the Levenshtein distance function to determine the closest match of `$username` to a string in a dictionary of names. You could use the dictionary only if there is no match in the database, even when you replace the characters to reduce the resources usage. PHP has such a function and it is called (to your surprise) `levenshtein()` - [more here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php).

If you can define stored procedures on your MySQL hosting, you can use the following routine (tested on MySQL 5.5.16):

```
CREATE FUNCTION `LEVENSHTEIN`(`s1` VARCHAR(255), `s2` VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNS int(11)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
  DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;
  DECLARE s1_char CHAR;
  DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256);
  SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = "0×00", j = 1, i = 1, c = 0;
  IF s1 = s2 THEN
    RETURN 0;
  ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN
    RETURN s2_len;
  ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN
    RETURN s1_len;
  ELSE
    WHILE j <= s2_len DO
      SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1;
    END WHILE;
    WHILE i <= s1_len DO
      SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1;
      WHILE j <= s2_len DO
        SET c = c + 1;
        IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1; END IF;
        SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost;
        IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
        SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1;
        IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
        SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1;
      END WHILE;
      SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
  END IF;
  RETURN c;
END
```

And your query might look like this one:

```
SELECT t1.`key` FROM `dict` AS t1 WHERE levenshtein("patryk", t1.`key`) < 5
```

Where `"patryk"` is your `$username` variable.

**EDIT**
I have just checked the query against the example input you provided (`DaryII` and `Daryll`) and it returns the correct row.

**EDIT 2**
You might also be interested in a percentage ratio. Use this function instead then:

```
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein_ratio( s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255) ) 
  RETURNS INT 
  DETERMINISTIC 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, max_len INT; 
    SET s1_len = LENGTH(s1), s2_len = LENGTH(s2); 
    IF s1_len > s2_len THEN  
      SET max_len = s1_len;  
    ELSE  
      SET max_len = s2_len;  
    END IF; 
    RETURN ROUND((1 - LEVENSHTEIN(s1, s2) / max_len) * 100); 
  END;
```

Both functions are taken from http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552

Answer (score 1):

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the problem by setting up a rule, which only allows lowercase letter in a username, except for the first letter. This could be accomplished with a regular expression like this:

```
if(preg_match('/^[A-Z]{0,1}[a-z]+$/', $username)){
    echo 'Username is allowed';
}else{
    echo 'Username is not allowed';
}
```

Comment: VERY HELPFUL! That gave me a good idea. I can make a rule that prevents the capital letter I if it's next to any other lowercase letter in the string except for the first character of that string.